# Tensorflow - Iterate over two Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two similar tensors; one has all the found valid boxes, and the other has all of the indexes where they belonged.

`Tensor("valid_boxes:0", shape=(?, 9), dtype=float32)`

`Tensor("valid_boxes_indexes:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=int64)`

I need a `map_fun` which access both variables. I tried this:

```
operation = tf.map_fn(lambda x: generate_bounding_box(x[0], x[1][1], x[1][0], x[1][2], grid_h, grid_w, anchors), (valid_boxes, valid_boxes_indexes))
```

Tensorflow gave me the following:

> ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
>
> First structure: type=tuple str=(tf.float32, tf.int64)
>
> Second structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("map_14/while/stack:0",
>   shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
>
> More specifically: Substructure "type=tuple str=(tf.float32,
>   tf.int64)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor
>   str=Tensor("map_14/while/stack:0", shape=(5,), dtype=float32)" is not

Is there any way to do this properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `dtype` when the input and output values do not have the same structure. From the documentation of [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

> Furthermore, `fn` may emit a different structure than its input. For example, `fn` may look like: `fn = lambda t1: return (t1 + 1, t1 - 1)`. In this case, the `dtype` parameter is not optional: `dtype` must be a type or (possibly nested) tuple of types matching the output of `fn`.

Try with this:

```
operation = tf.map_fn(
    lambda x: generate_bounding_box(x[0], x[1][1], x[1][0], x[1][2],
                                    grid_h, grid_w, anchors),
    (valid_boxes, valid_boxes_indexes)
    dtype=tf.float32)
```